# Issue with java script code trying to make a Tip Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

As a practice (i'm a beginner), i'm trying to create a restaurant tip calculator, who tells you how much money should you pay on tip, depending on the country your in.

Well, my code doesn't work, and i have no idea why...
When i click on the submit, nothing happens, and i don't know why..

If you'll take a look on the code, and tell me if you have any idea what's the problem, i'll be thankful.

The code:

```
    <form action="">

    <span>Please select your country: </span>
                <select name="country" id="select-country">
                            <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                            <option value="USA">USA</option>
                </select>
                <br/>

                <span>Please enter the price of the dish: </span>
                        <input type="number" max="999" id="number"></input>
                        </br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
    </form>
 <span> Your Tip: </span>
                     <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                                     var list = document.getElementById("select-country");
                                     var country = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
                                     var price = document.getElementById("number").value;

                                     if (country == "Israel"){
                                                print 'your tip is: ' price/100*12 ;
                                     }
                 </script>
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `document.write`, `alert` or `console.log` instead of `print`? `window.print()` attempts to print the page (to your printer).

Comment: you want to print the statement means, use document.write or alert()

Comment: You have *no* trigger on your submit button by the way. (onclick etc.)

Comment: I think you should learn to write valid HTML code, then basic JavaScript properties, like declaring global functions, then assigning them to HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function calcAmt(amountType){
    var price = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var country=amountType;
        if (country == "Israel"){
            document.getElementById('amt').innerHTML=price/100*12;
        }
}
</script>
<span>Please select your country: </span>
<select name="country" id="select-country" onchange="calcAmt(this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Country</option> 
    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<br/>
<span>Please enter the price of the dish: </span>
<input type="number" max="999" id="number"></input>
</br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
<span> Your Tip: </span>
<span id="amt"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a javascript function call to your submit button click...

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:GetTip()"></input>
```

Add the function declaration around your javascript, and use valid javascript code to display it...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetTip() {
                                     var list = document.getElementById("select-country");
                                     var country = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
                                     var price = document.getElementById("number").value;

                                     if (country == "Israel"){
                                                alert( 'your tip is: ' + price/100*12 );
                                     }
    }
                 </script>
```

There's no "print" function in javascript that I'm aware of.